# How to compare Time (hour and minute) using JSON (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, json, angular, time

I have to save a beginning time (hour and minutes) and an end time on my application as a string, because I'm using JSON.

Later I'll have to compare those times to enable or disable a functionality that will allow the user to create a new appointment.

My question is: how can I compare those string times so the user will not be able to create an appointment between those two times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare time using the Date class in javascript and also create the class with a constructor passing a string having date and time both.

Using only time, you would need to append the date or compare it manually.
e.g. comparing using Date class:

let check = new Date("2018-05-12 14:47:40") > new Date("2018-05-12 14:17:40")

Comment: That’s just perfect, Deependra! Tkss a lot.